# MultiValueDictKeyError at /add

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Each time I add Project with Expense Category. It's displaying error in the browser

[image: Error Image]

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /add 'categoriesString'

Although the Project is getting saved in the database!

Please help me to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the form's html field put `name="categoriesString"` for the input field where you are passing data

Comment: Do you've any idea how to use MongoDB with Django?